# Aggregate measure as a parallel period up to parallel date

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

The goal is to sum values up to the given date. So when the user chooses date range from 2021-01-01 to 2021-02-07 and aggregates it daily, the aggregation for each day is the running sum of parallel period in previous year i month aggregation.

So the value for 2021-01-01 would be 2020-01-03 (monday to monday).
The value for 2021-01-05 would be running sum of values from range 2020-01-03 to 2021-01-07.

So we are trying to catch the given date and return the sum of values that fall between the start of parallel period of previous year and the date.

Sample code:

```
    [date selected] 
EXISTING [Report date].[Date YQMD].[Day]    
    
    
sum(    
{   
ParallelPeriod( [Report date].[Date YQMD].[Year],   
1,  HEAD([date selected],1).Item(0) ) 

:   
ParallelPeriod( [Report date].[Date YQMD].[Year],   
1,  TAIL([date selected],1).Item(0) ) 

     }, 
        [Measures].[TTV])
```

So we try to catch the date in current aggegation and sum TTV for the parallel period of previous year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PrevMember, check out the documentation :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/prevmember-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15